# Align date format for all dates

Tags: biblatex

I´m having trouble with dates in LaTeX using biblatex. I´d like to use the date format **dd.mm.yyyy** across the whole document. Currently I´m struggling with the **urldate** command inside my .bib file.

A sample bib-entry:

```
@Online{heartbleedCVE,
  title   = {Heartbleed: CVE-2014-0160},
  author  = {MITRE},
  url     = {https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-0160},
  date    = {2014-04-10},
  urldate = {2017-11-05}
}
```

From my preamble:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, a4paper, parskip=full-, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, headsepline]{scrartcl}
    
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    maxcitenames=5,
    maxbibnames=1000,
    backend=biber,
    urldate=edtf,
    seconds=true,
    style=alphabetic]
    {biblatex}
\addbibresource{resources/sources.bib}
```

The output:

[image]

As you can see both date formats are not dd.mm.yyyy. yyyy-mm-dd is the only input format that´s accepted by date and urldate.

Is there a way to align all date formats accross the document? So far I´ve only had problems with the urldate parameter but i´m sure there might be other date-related

Comment: The expected input is always `YYYY-MM-DD` (ISO/EDTF). With `urldate=edtf,` you request EDTF *output* and that is `YYYY-MM-DD` in your case. If you just leave it away the default `urldate=short` kicks in and you get a nice output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You load `biblatex` with the option

```
urldate=edtf,
```

That option causes the `urldate` to be displayed in EDTF/ISO format, i.e. as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

The  default setting is `urldate=short,` ('10.04.2017'). Most other dates, however, are printed with the `comp` option ('10. April 2017'). If you want all dates to use `short` you can go with

```
alldates=short, labeldate=year
```

`alldates` sets all date formats known to `biblatex` to the same value at once. The `labeldate=year` is necessary so that the date in citations is still only the year and not the full date (with `biblatex` >= 3.8).

The expected input is always EDTF/ISO-compliant `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: moewe, I had looked in the documentation and, on second thought, it is no wonder I didn't get it right. In the documentation, the text for the option `alldates`, states "Sets the option for all dates in the datamodel to the same value. The date fields in the default data model are `date`, `origdate`, `eventdate` and `urldate`." No `labeldate`. Am I missing something, or is the documentation?

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, the documentation does not list `labeldate` there, even though `alldates` also applies to `labeldate`.